# JQuery Validation for radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two radio button for agree and for disagree
I need to force user to choose I Agree

For that I write the validation

```
<input type="radio" id="ia" name="dc" value="true">I Agree
<input type="radio" id="id" name="dc" checked="checked" value="false">I Disagree

  jQuery("#frm_ads").validate({
    rules: {


    dc: {required: function(element) {
                        return $('input[name="dc"]:checked').val() == 'true';
                  }}
```

But this validation is not working .

If any one have solution then please help me .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
return $('#ia').is(':checked');
```

Comment: but if Disagree is checked then form can not submitted but here not happen for is submited

Comment: If "agree" is checked, the standard working of radio buttons with the same names ensures the other one isn't checked.

Comment: Still not working . I have include jquery.validate.min.js is any othe file need for this?